# Any other way of saying "I share your opinion"?

Tags: phrases

"I divide your position" is the first that came to my mind, but I think it's definitely incorrect. Is there any phrase like this with "position", not "opinion"?

Comment: What's wrong with "I share your position"?

Comment: "Seconded". "Agreed". "Accord".

Comment: If you say "I concur," you don't have to add anything else.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here are some more conversational ways to say "I share your opinion".:

*My position is the same as yours.*

*I hold the same position.*

*I share your position.*

*We share the same position.*

*My thoughts exactly.*

*I feel likewise.*

*I feel the same way.*

*We are of the same mind.*

Answer (score 2):

> I am of the same mind.
>
> I agree with you.
>
> I have the same opinion.
>
> I have the same feelings. [In some cases]

Answer (score 1):

We are **[on the same page](http://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/on+the+same+page)**.

A fine list of [idiomatic expressions](https://english.stackexchange.com/a/40222/14666) meaning the same thing on a scale!

Answer (score 0):

How about this?

> I agree with your position

Answer (score 0):

We're ***on the same wavelength***

> on the same wavelength
>
> : in agreement
>
> [Cambridge Dictionary of American Idioms](http://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/Wavelength)