# What is the appropriate phrase to say if two people are on the same track?

Tags: phrase-requests, sentence, syntactic-analysis, speech

I am sharing my understanding regarding a particular matter with a colleague just to make sure that both of we have same understanding. This is just to avoid any conflict or confusion among us. Phrases coming to my mind are like:

> making sure we are on the same horizon or stage
>
> making sure we are aligned
>
> making sure we are on the same track

What would be the most appropriate sentence in this regard?

Comment: “Aligned” / “in alignment” or “on the same page” are what are most common in my circles.

Comment: What's wrong with "making sure we're on the same page"?

Comment: And usually when we are on the same page that means they’re on the right track.  ;-)

Comment: As others have said, "on the same page" means exactly that and is completely unambiguous. But if you really want to say two people are really, really on the same page? "They're jibing man." No, don't say that, but if two things are working well together, you can say "they're jibing", but I wouldn't, personally, apply that to people.

Comment: Just a note on your own examples: I would probably avoid *on the same horizon*, as it may imply that you want to make sure you are both going to *finish* at the same time, without any implications about agreement along the way to that finish. ("Horizon" in business often means how long for something to be completed.) *On the same stage* has a similar issue, in that it might suggest that you want to be on the same step of the process, but without suggesting anything about your respective attitudes. (Think of "stages of a project" rather than theatrical stages.)

Comment: If the OP shares a friendship with his colleague that transcends the regular work environment, then one might resonably tell such a colleague that, "Great minds think alike" in order to signal the OP's intention.

Comment: "make sure we're seeing eye to eye" is another common expression.

Comment: What's wrong with "making sure we are on the same track"? It seems like you had what you wanted. Perhaps "On the same page" sounds a little more common, but "track" doesn't sound any less familiar. If you are working with someone who is unfamiliar with common English expressions then you might was to avoid an expression of any type. Certainly, "horizon" sounds weird. "Stage" is the most literal and may be best if you do want to avoid an idiom. But all these would make sense to me.

Comment: If they're on the same track?  "Boy, you'd better jump.
Cuz there's two locomotives and they're going to bump."

Answer (score 32):

"Making sure we are ***on the same page***." would be even better than the options you mentioned.  Although I don't think your suggestions would be misunderstood, what I have suggested is a more common way of saying it.  See below.  [image] [Reference](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=on%20the%20same%20page%2C%20on%20the%20same%20track%2C%20on%20the%20same%20horizon%2C%20on%20the%20same%20stage&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Con%20the%20same%20page%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Con%20the%20same%20track%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Con%20the%20same%20horizon%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Con%20the%20same%20stage%3B%2Cc0)

Comment: Irrelevant to the topic really but as an aside I really find interesting the difference when you choose AmE and BrE on that particularly ngram

Answer (score 9):

In addition to "on the same page" (which was my first thought) as already mentioned, you can also use "***in sync***" or "***in agreement***".

> making sure we are ***in sync***
>   making sure we are ***in agreement***

ODO:

> [*Phrases*]
>   **[in (or out of) sync](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/sync)** [*informal*]
>   Working well (or badly) together; **in (or out of) agreement.**
>
> ‘To share life, we must spend time together and find ways to be in
>   sync.’
>
> **[agreement](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/agreement)**
>   *NOUN* [*mass noun*]
>   **1** Harmony or accordance in opinion or feeling.
>
> ‘Your Honour, I think we are ***in agreement*** that the matter should
>   be heard as soon as possible.’

Answer (score 5):

I am stuck choosing between two options:

- On the same page (already answered)
- On the same wavelength.

On the surface, they mean pretty much the same thing. However, I make a distinction between the two.

Let's image there are two people, colleagues who work closely together. They agree on certain topic. I would say they are on the same **page**.

However, if I'm talking about two people who are not aware of eachother; but who (unknowingly) consistently have the same opinion, I would refer to them as being on the same **wavelength**

To me, being on the same page means you interacted with the other person to make sure you are in sync with one another (= you are in agreement on a topic you have specifically addressed)
Being on the same wavelength, however, describes an innate state of being similar enough to another person, without intentionally having to make sure. (= your mindset/character is similar enough that you would respond similarly to a topic that you haven't experienced yet).

E.g. when we're talking about how twins, even when separated, will make the same decisions consistently, I would call that being on the same wavelength, and **not** being on the same page (because the twins did not make sure that they made the same choices, it just happened automatically)

If that makes sense.

Answer (score 4):

A more traditional version of *on the same page* might be

- to ***[see eye to eye](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/see-eye-to-eye)***

ie. to be in agreement with

Comment: ohk i just came to know about this phrase otherwise i was just familiar with [another version of eye to eye](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=_8Gx6AFMJ9U)

Answer (score 1):

I think **being on the same page** means a shared understanding, but not necessarily being in agreement about something.

See: [Meaning of “on the same page"](https://english.stackexchange.com/a/40210)